# How do I using Application Designer, add Failure Class field from different Maximo table to Work Order Tracking?

Tags: maximo

We want to "Categorize" our work orders more systematically. So far, we've been using Description, but we feel it is not a reliable way. We were hoping to use Failure Class as a starting point, but we find that having on a different tab discourages technicians and the help desk from classifying the work order.

Is it possible to add/duplicate the Failure Class field to Work Order Tracking screen?

Normally, I wouldn't ask, but was not clear if this was possible because Failure Class, Codes, and Tracking are different tables in Maximo. So, I wasn't sure how this would work exactly...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to use Application Designer's copy / paste functionality to duplicate the field. The specific field in question is on the top level of the Work Order Tracking application and facilitates interaction with the FAILURECODE attribute of the Main Object of the application, which is WORKORDER. Therefore, a copy / paste operation should be all you need. (Note: Application Designer's copy / paste functionality is used via that application's toolbar buttons, not Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V.) And if using Application Designer's copy / paste functionality doesn't work to your satisfaction, I would recommend exporting the XML for the application, copying the line of XML as desired and giving it a unique `id`, and importing the updated XML back in to Maximo. (Application Designer has toolbar buttons for exporting and importing an application's XML.)

You mentioned difficulty getting users to fill it in as a driver for asking the question. Another solution, which you can do as well as or instead of copying the field, is to specify the Failure Class on each Asset. Then, when an Asset is put on a Work Order, its Failure Class will be copied over, saving the users work and risk of not choosing correctly. And another idea is to highlight the Failure tab until a Failure Class is supplied.

And you also mentioned that the driver behind getting them to fill in the Failure Class, and etc, was to help categorize work. To that point, you should know that Failure Classes, in specific, and Failure Codes, in general, are intended to be used to help you determine what's going wrong with your assets, how often, and how the problems are being fixed. So, using them to categorize work is a bad idea. Instead, you should be using the Work Type field and Classifications, because categorizing work is what these are meant to be used for. The Work Type field is already on the Work Order tab, and Classifications fields are on the Specifications tab. You could copy the Classifications fields the same as I directed above for the Failure Class field.